# Productive Eclipse Shorcuts

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I currently use a variety of keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse such as:

```
Ctrl + Shift + R: Open Resources
Ctrl + F6: Switch Files in Editor
Ctrl + Q, ? To switch to desired window
Ctrl + Alt + R: To Restart My server
Ctrl + O: To view an outline of a class
F12: to go to the editor
```

What are some other productive shortcuts I may not be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my frequently used hot keys and I do think they improve my productivity very much

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to use the code templates that are defined in the `Windows→Preferences→Java→Editor→Template`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to find files of any type.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to organize imports and  import the missing imports automatically

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>  on a variables / functions to go to its declaration

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>  on a method or class shows the whole inheritance tree, for example all methods which implement an interface.

Answer (score 4):

```
Shift + Ctr + L
```

This opens the list of keyboard shortcuts ;-)

Comment: I don't see how sorting through +100 shortcuts is going to increase my productivity

Answer (score 4):

My favorite is quick access: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and start typing anything you are looking for...

Comment: this seems to work the same as Ctrl+0, still I appreciate you sharing it and taking the question seriously.

Comment: @kmb385 Quick access is quite different from quick outline, it gives you access to all workbench elements - like views, perspectives, preferences, etc.

Comment: This is my favourite.  It also allows access to commands that don't yet have a keybinding, and will allow searching via the first characters of the name.