# Matching with varargs() gives compilation error

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a class which has a method which accepts variable number of arguments. Below is sample code-

```
class MyClass{
    public List<String> getMulti(String... keys){//}
}
MyClass mc = mock(MyClass.class);
when(mc.getmValues(anyVararg())).thenReturn(someList);
```

Note, however, that with this code I get a compilation error-
The method getMulti(String...) in the type MyClass is not applicable for the arguments (Object). Could someone help me resolve this?

Also, before trying anyVararg(), I used the following method However, the matcher did not work and the method getmValues didn't return "someList" (it returned an empty list).

```
when(mc.getmValues(any(String[].class))).thenReturn(someList);
```

and the method was invoked with a String[].

Would appreciate help on this one too (as to what I might have done wrong).

Thank you
Neelesh

Comment: Have you tried explicitly filling in the type parameter on anyVararg()? `when(mc.getmValues(Mockito.<String[]>anyVararg())).thenReturn(someList);`

Comment: Thanks a ton Grove and pobrelkey. I feel so miserable! I should have thought of this myself in the first place. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cast your `anyVararg(`) to `String[]` you should have no problem:

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
    List<String> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyClass mc = mock(MyClass.class);
    when(mc.getMulti((String[]) anyVararg())).thenReturn(expectedList);
    assertSame(expectedList, mc.getMulti(""));
}
```

**EDIT** (this would not fit in the comment below)

Most people are not aware of many cool features the IDEs have and which are meant to make our life easier. For example CTRL+1 in Eclipse and ALT+ENTER in IDEA are the shortcuts for "suggestions on the current problem". So just click in the editor on `anyVararg()`, use the shortcut and you'll see the list of suggested fixes, casting to String[] inclued.

There are many more where those came from ([Productive Eclipse Shorcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634104/productive-eclipse-shorcuts) or [DZone's Effective Eclipse Shortcuts](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key)) so you should try tinkering around with your "tool".

Comment: Thanks a ton Grove and pobrelkey. I feel so miserable! I should have thought of this myself in the first place. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem and you definitely should not need to feel miserable because we all make silly mistakes and they are a normal part of the learning process. I'm assuming you use an IDE so let me give you a piece of advice which is too long to fit here, so I'm adding it to my original answer :)

Comment: This looks like a solid answer, OP - would you like to accept it (green tick) ?

Comment: Grove, you probably solved many more problems for me even before they arose. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're most welcome and please feel free to do the same when you have the chance. Cheers